# check if string is in format "coordinate/coordinate"

Tags: c++, string, coordinates

I would love to know how to check if a string has the format of two coordinates, like:

```
(signed int x,signed int y)
```

I've already found some answers via search but I don't quite get them yet (just started with c++) and I'm asking for a simple solution or hint how to check this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever heard about Regex ?

Comment: You probably want regular expressions. Check out some tutorials, there is a ton of them online.

Comment: Regarding regular expressions, [read this first](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems). If you decide that regular expression is still a solution to your problem (which it very well may be, don't disregard it entirely) then read about [the regular expression support in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

Comment: I do know regex, but I didn't know  you can use them in c++ (I just knew them from a website sorting algorithm). I'll have a look at it, thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify that either the example you gave was generic or a concrete example, as well as specify how this input is received? I.E. are you literally parsing a `cstring`/`std::string` object trying to identify it's tokens? are you finding this embedded within a string? Can you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this one (some simpler might exist):

```
^\(\-{0,1}\d*,\-{0,1}\d*\)
```

Which is:

```
^\(       start by a parenthesis
\-{0,1}   0 or 1 "-"
\d*       any digit
,         ","
```

and repeat.

Comment: @Yíu please read this [about the C++ Regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need to take specifically a string as input. I'd check each value of the string.

```
string str;
// something happens to str, to make it a coordinate
int n = 0;
int m = 48;
bool isANumber;
bool hasASlash = false;
while ((n < str.length()) and isANumber) {
    isANumber = false;
    if (str.at(n) == '/') {
        hasASlash = true; // this means there is a slash somewhere in it
    }
    while ((m <= 57) and !isANumber) {
        // makes sure the character is a number or slash
        if ((str.at(n) == m) or (str.at(n) == '/')) isANumber = true;
        m++;
    }
    m = 48;
    n++;
}
if (hasASlash and isANumber) {
    // the string is in the right format
}
```

Please correct me if I've done something wrong...